# Cannot compile static array with fixed size

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Minimal code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int a = 5;
    static int b[a];
    return 0;
}
```

Looks fine, eh? Variable `a` is constant. Works with 4.4 too.

```
gcc -v
gcc version 6.2.1 20160830 (GCC)
gcc 1.c
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:6:16: error: storage size of ‘b’ isn’t constant
     static int b[a];
```

Btw, clang compiles this code well.

Comment: Only wondering why this is not treated as VLA...

Comment: @SouravGhosh Because of `static`.

Comment: It compiles fine on [https://gcc.godbolt.org/](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) with gcc and clang.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Try `-Werror=pedantic`, compilation will fail.  This is not a standards-conformant C program.

Comment: @DietrichEpp still compiles fine even with `-Werror=pedantic`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Now *that's* a GCC bug.

Comment: There are no bugs in any compiler here. Both behaviors conform to C11. Point 10 in §6.6 says: "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions."

Answer (score 6):

Arrays declared as `static` or at file scope (i.e. having *static storage duration*) cannot be variable length arrays:

From section 6.7.6.2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If  an  identifier  is  declared  as  having  a  variably  modified 
>   type,  it  shall  be  an  ordinary identifier  (as  defined  in 
>   6.2.3),  have  no linkage,  and  have  either  block  scope  or  function prototype  scope.  **If  an  identifier  is  declared  to  be 
>   an  object  with  static  or  thread  storage duration, it shall not
>   have a variable length array type.**

Even though the length is specified by a `const int`, it is not considered a **constant expression**.  Even using a size of type `static const int` doesn't satisfy this requirement.

Note that this is different in C++, where a `static const int` is considered a constant expression.  C++11 also defines the `constexpr` keyword for this purpose.

Comment: Of course I'd also say that in C++ `const int` is considered `constexpr` only if it has `constexpr` initializer. Also, it seems that you don't even need `static` for it (at least it works without on gcc on godbolt).

Comment: Well, actually it's problem in clang, it doesn't correspond to standard.

Comment: @БорисСтепанов It's not a problem in clang. Both behaviors are legal from the point of C11 (and C99) standard. A compiler is allowed to treat anything as a constant expression if it can justify it. The standard only says what must be a constant, but allows anything to be a constant expression.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Sorry, I misread your comment.